# Difference between specifying argument and not in NumPy

Tags: python

Running these lines in Colab:

```
import numpy as np
size  = 2**13
%timeit np.random.normal(size=(size, size))
print("-----------")
%timeit np.random.normal((size, size))
```

yields:

```
1 loop, best of 5: 2.67 s per loop
-----------
The slowest run took 7.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 5: 16.3 µs per loop
```

Why is the difference in computational time between these two lines of code so large? In my mind they should be the same.

Comment: Could it be because the first two parameters are the mean and variance?

Comment: This programming question is better suited to a programming site such as [scicomp.se] or [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This due to the order of optional arguments. Perhaps this example can explain thing for you:

```
def foo(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3):
    print((x, y, z))
```

```
In [1]: foo()
(1, 2, 3)

In [2]: foo(4)
(4, 2, 3)

In [3]: foo(z = 4)
(1, 2, 4)
```

Now looking at help about `np.random.normal`, we get:

```
In [4]: help(np.random.normal)
Help on built-in function normal:

normal(...) method of mtrand.RandomState instance
    normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
```

That means that since `loc` is the first optional argument, `np.random.normal((size, size))` is interpreted as `np.random.normal(loc = (size, size))` and not as `np.random.normal(size = (size, size))`